# Alternative to GPU Screen Recorder and SimpleScreenRecorder on Linux OS?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, xorg

Here I want to share my problem while using a screen recorder like GPU Screen Recorder or SimpleScreenRecorder.

What I get here is sometimes I got problems from

```
`root permission`
```

before running a program, so basically I need to run the screen recorder program with "sudo -i" or pkexec or polkit but sometimes I faced a problem with authorization. that is my first problem here.

Second, the plugins that are needed by GUI programs I need to run are not available by Linux distro or deprecated version. so I need to find plugin files that have the same version needed by the screen recorder program. For example an error below.

> mpv: error while loading shared libraries: libavcodec.so.59: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Third, I found an alternative program that is provided by most Linux distro, it's ffmpeg but needs some extra configuration to run perfectly suited with hardware devices.

I personally use Xfce Linux which is suited well to my CPU hardware capability and compatibility.

Comment: I am not even sure if this is a question ?

Comment: thanks for your feedback, wanna try to post something here to share, sorry

Answer (score 0):

Here I found a better and more flexible configuration after doing some suggestions from sites and tutorial videos with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -f x11grab -video_size 1280x720 -framerate 30 -i :0.0 -f pulse -i ladspa_output.mbeq_1197.mbeq.monitor -preset fast -crf 22 -c:a aac -b:v 6M -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:a 128k ~/Videos/Recording-$(date +%F-%I-%M-%N).mp4
```

With the script above, we can make an adjustment to the video bitrate (`-b:v 6M`) and make some improvements to the FPS of the video result by changing (`-preset fast`) and (`-crf 22`).

To understand better about our audio hardware, you can check the link below with a little explanation.

Link to shell script [here](https://github.com/unmeimusu/fsc/blob/main/fsc.sh).

Comment: wait let me correct the post